# How to draw a rectangle using a mouse in C# (emgucv)?

Tags: c#, mouse, emgucv

I want to draw a rectangle using a mouse on video frame (i.e picture box), just like when we select any files. The user will click mouse button select the area and will release the mouse button. Just like snipping or crop!

I m using emgucv!

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

namespace Emgucv33Apps
{
public partial class FormCropImage : Form
{
    Image<Bgr, byte> imgInput;
    Rectangle rect;
    Point StartLocation;
    Point EndLcation;
    bool IsMouseDown = false;

    public FormCropImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            imgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ofd.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = imgInput.Bitmap;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMouseDown = true;
        StartLocation = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseDown==true)
        {
            EndLcation = e.Location;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rect!=null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, GetRectangle());
        }
    }

    private Rectangle GetRectangle()
    {
        rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.X = Math.Min( StartLocation.X,EndLcation.X);
        rect.Y = Math.Min(StartLocation.Y, EndLcation.Y);
        rect.Width = Math.Abs(StartLocation.X - EndLcation.X);
        rect.Height = Math.Abs(StartLocation.Y - EndLcation.Y);

        return rect;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMouseDown==true)
        {
            EndLcation = e.Location;
            IsMouseDown = false;
            if (rect!=null)
            {
                imgInput.ROI = rect;
                Image<Bgr, byte> temp = imgInput.CopyBlank();
                imgInput.CopyTo(temp);
                imgInput.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;
                pictureBox2.Image = temp.Bitmap;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: replace the open file dialog with a capture event and this will do exactly what you need.If you are in need of more help with this let me know ill write you a working sample

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Image<B, T>.Draw` method. It's shown in the [Shape detection in C#](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp) example code. Here is a snippet from the link:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> triangleRectangleImage = img.CopyBlank();
foreach (MCvBox2D box in boxList)
   triangleRectangleImage.Draw(box, new Bgr(Color.DarkOrange), 2);
```

Comment: I m talking about this, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCu4_mhcdJg check the way they are drawing rectangle.

Comment: @Andy alright, but in the question you talk about the mouse? Did you try my sample? The rectangle will look like the one in the video, except that it is orange and not white.

Comment: I can draw rectangle, but I want user to select region by mouse just the way we crop pictures (like a bounding box)

Comment: @Andy I keep searching for a method to dynamically draw a rectangle but till now (2018), no answer.